# Message listener on Symphony

Tags: python, chatbot, symphony-cms

I am working on a chatbot that is to be implemented in the Symphony messaging environment: https://rest-api.symphony.com

I have already implemented the methods I need to post and read messages. However, I am stuck at the implementation of the bot "listener", as it seems there is no obvious way to do that in Symphony. Ideally I would have them call my API when a "new message" event happens, so I can process it immediately.

For now my solution is to call their API every X seconds and check if there is any new message. This is obviously not very efficient.... **Anybody has an idea how to improve this process?**

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to read messages without polling is to use DataStream. You can find the proper documentation here:

https://rest-api.symphony.com/docs/create-messagesevents-stream-v4
https://YOUR_POD_SUBDOMAIN.symphony.com/agent/v4/datafeed/:id/read

Note that every datastream created has a 30sec timeout if no message arrives. You need therefore to implement a recursive function to re-create the datastream every time you hit the timeout.

Hope this helps.

[symphony-chat](/questions/tagged/symphony-chat)